# when I use py2exe to get exe from python ,I got this error" Traceback (most recent call last)"

Tags: python, py2exe

**when I use py2exe to get exe from python ,I got this error：**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pronterface.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "printrun\pronterface.pyc", line 32, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "printrun\pronsole.pyc", line 33, in <module>
  ImportError: No module named serial
```

This  opensource program named Printrun form https://github.com/uki1/Print
what should I do?

Comment: Use the precompiled binaries..?

Comment: I'm a green hand of Python,I'm not really sure about this stuff(precompiled binaries) is what :)

Comment: At the bottom of the page in your link are instructions for installing.